# What is the correct way to construct categories using Laravel

Tags: laravel, categories, categorical-data

We have a digital platform whose function is to enable the user to create an online store on his own

We are facing a problem with the categories. They are built in, but they take a very long time to load on the browser

What is the correct way to build it lightly and suitable for server and browser

[Screenshot to show the time taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcIS7.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is rendering by js libraries, maybe using browser localStorage helps you load it faster.
But if you are rendering it by yourself, It is a good practice to store categories as depicted in the image below.
[image]

and use caching mechanism to store the menu structure in memory and retrieve it in the front-end so fast.